# Geometry of Curves and Surfaces

Tags: differential-geometry

The following is a question regarding Elementary Geometry of Differentiable Curves.

> Venture a guess of the number of irregular values of $t$ for the trochoid with $h = 1, \lambda = \frac{m}{n}$, where $m,n$ are coprime integers, $m \neq 0, n > 1$. Note: $m$ could be negative.

The Trochoid is as follows:
\begin{equation}
 z(t) = (\lambda + 1)e^{it} - he^{i(\lambda + 1)t}
\end{equation}
An irregular values of $t$ occurs when $z^{'}(t) = 0$. Now $z^{'}(t) = i(\lambda + 1)e^{it} - i(\lambda + 1)he^{i(\lambda +1)t}.$

\begin{eqnarray}
\Rightarrow & & [i(\lambda + 1]\cdot[e^{it} - he^{i(\lambda + 1)t}] = 0\\
\Rightarrow & & [e^{it} - he^{i(\lambda + 1)t}] = 0\\
\Rightarrow & & e^{it} = he^{i(\lambda + 1)t}\\
\Rightarrow & & 1 = he^{i\lambda t} \Rightarrow \frac{1}{h} = e^{i\lambda t}
\end{eqnarray}

Here is where things get interesting. Letting $h = 1$ and $\lambda = \frac{m}{n}$, we get

\begin{eqnarray}
1 &=& e^{i\frac{m}{n}t}\\
& = & \cos(\frac{m}{n}t) + i\sin(\frac{m}{n}t)\\
& \Rightarrow & \cos(\frac{m}{n}t) = 1\\
& & \sin(\frac{m}{n}t) = 0
\end{eqnarray}

This is where I am stuck. If we take the cosine inverse of the first expression, we get 
\begin{equation}
\frac{m}{n}t = 0 + 2\pi k, k \in \textbf{Z}
\end{equation}

Of course we have two cases where $m$ is either positive or negative. But since cosine is even, I assume it would not effect it in either case. So my answer here is how to I determine how many irregular values of $t$ do we have? Before you say infinite, according to the professor, it is finite. Why? If I am not mistaken, we are looking at an interval of $\theta = [0 ,2\pi)$

Thank you for your feedback and Thanks in Advance.